# Skype Bookmarked Chat Issue

Tags: macos, mac, unix, skype

I have a desktop running Ubuntu 11.04 and a MacBook Pro. I have 2 bookmarked chats under Linux version of Skype, but it's not showing under Mac version.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chat bookmarks only work locally on your machine, these are not synchronized across different machines

more over, chat history is stored locally but normally last 30 days update/sync across different machines